# Images randomly placed and resized within wrapper

Tags: image, random, position, size

I've a wrapper that takes the 100% of the page, and within the wrapper a set of some images (now they are 5, but they'll eventually become 10 or more) which I'd like to randomly place and resize so to fit the wrapper.

```
<div id="wrapper">
 <img src="images/body/cervello.png" id="image" class="brain" />
 <img src="images/body/chiappe.png" id="image" class="booty" />
 <img src="images/body/cuore.png" id="image" class="heart" />
 <img src="images/body/denti.png" id="image" class="teeth" />
 <img src="images/body/mano.png" id="image" class="hand" />
 <img src="images/body/orecchio.png" id="image" class="ear" />
</div>

body, html {
height: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
height: 100%;
margin: 0px auto;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

I'm very much a newbie to coding, so not yet able to write my own JS..though I've found [this code on a JSFiddle](https://codepen.io/Afterlame/pen/gevJr) that supposedly does what I need to do (at least for the placement, not for the resizing).

The other problem is indeed trying to calculate the full size of the window and making sure that the resizing of all the images can be accordingly, so to not have them overlapping, getting too big/small etc..

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1KSx.jpg) is pretty much what I'd like to achieve, but with images instead of bubbles..

I hope I've explained somehow what I'd like to achieve..I've tried to be as clear as possible so to help you with understanding my goal :)

Thanks very much in advance for your time!

Comment: I've figured it out using this code: https://www.codingforums.com/html-and-css/264640-random-position-div.html
Only problem I'd like to solve, if possible, is to avoid having divs overlapping each other, if possible?!

Thanks again for your help :)